# Measuring quantitative metrics in Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

My team and I are trying to measure quantitive metrics in Google Analytics and we're not sure what's the best way to do so.

We're a privacy app with a photo vault and we want to measure the number of items a user saves within the app, for example for a user who uploaded 10 photos to the app, but we're not sure how to do so.

An event seems wrong because we don't want an event for each import of content a user makes, for example:
if the user flow is:

Day 1 - Upload 3 items

Day 2 - Uploaded 5 items.

Day 3 - Removed 2 items.

at the end of day 3, we want to see that this specific user now has 6 items in the app, and we want to be able to filter it by: "Show me all the users that currently have 5 items or more in the app".

We also tried User property but it doesn't work because we cant filter it like I wrote above, any suggestions?